# Нужен ли интерфейс или абстрактный класс?

Tags: java

В ООП пока не силен, так что отсюда и вопрос. Есть БД на MySQl, в ней 20таблиц. Приложение пишу на Java. Создаю для обработки каждой таблицы, отдельный класс. Первый вопрос - правильно ли так делать? И второй, нужен ли мне здесь интерфейс или какой то класс, от которого потом все будет наследоваться. Дело в том, что поля, понятное дело у всех этих классов разные, и методы в общем то разные. Методы то похожи все, но реализация разная, это понятно, здесь нужен или интерфейс или класс родитель, но похожи в основном только 3 метода(выборка, удаление, обновление), но и то, в некоторых классах есть несколько методов на выборку данных из БД. Так что если подумать, то похожи только 2 метода(удаление и изменение записи). Собственно вот это и вводит в ступор. Нужно ли из-за пары однотипных методов делать интерфейс или класс родитель, если каждый класс в любом случае будет реализовывать ити пару методов по своему? Если что-то делаю не так, подскажите.

Comment: Если таблицы разные, то нет смысла делать у них всех общего предка.

Comment: @KoVadim таблицы разные все. А правильно вообще так делать? Для каждой таблицы создавать класс? Или как лучше?

Comment: А кто его знает, что в тех таблицах. Может быть есть смысл один класс на две таблицы или три класса на одну. А может и java там не нужна. Кто его знает.

Comment: Код не пишут потому что «так правильно» и [«все так делают»](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82). Интерфейсы и классы должны использоваться в коде и выполнять задачи. Соответственно, они нужны когда используются и не нужны когда не используются. Точнее для общего случая не ответить.

Comment: В общем-то в этом нет ничего плохого. Можете так же посмотреть как реализуются паттерн DAO и паттерн Repository для работы с базой данных.

Answer (score 1):

Раз все таблицы разные, судя по описанию в вопросе, то нет смысла делать ни предка, ни интерфейс. Создаешь просто для каждой отдельной таблицы свой класс, так называемую сущность или бин, у которого будут только поля (соответствующие полям в таблице) и get/set методы для доступа к их значениям. 
Методы работы с базой данных лучше вынести в отдельный класс, как уже упоминал @artex_x в своем ответе.